# Nodemailer not working when sending email in a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, nodemailer

Following is the code for sending an email via forget password hit, which is not working, however if the same code run via file it is sending an email..let me know what I am doing wrong with the callback usage.

Following is the code, which is working but **not** sending an email -

```
app.post('/forget', function(req, res){
  var userEmail = req.body.email;
  User.findOne({email: userEmail}, function(err, user){
    if (err) {
      res.send({"message": "Wrong!", "err": err, "status_code": "500"});
    }
    else{
      var password = "12345";
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
          service: "Gmail",
          auth: {
              user: "XXXXX@gmail.com",
              pass: "YYYYY"
          }
      });
      var mailOptions = {
          from: "Team | <XXXXX@gmail.com>",
          to: user.email,
          subject: "Password Change",
          text: "Hello world",
          html: "Your password changed successfully."+ "Your new password is "+ "<style='color: red;'>"+ password +"</style>" // html body
      };   
      console.log(mailOptions);
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
          if(error){
              console.log(error);
          }else{
              console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
          }
      });        

      user.password = password;
      user.save(function(err){
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        else return res.send({"message": "success", "data": user, "status_code": "200"});
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Error it is throwing -

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

FYI - I am using `var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");` above the code so that is not the case.

Working code -

Now if I put the same code in a file and run via `node mail.js` command then mail sent successfully.

**Let me know what I am doing wrong here if any**

Working code (just a duplicate code )

```
  var password = "12345";
  var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
      service: "Gmail",
      auth: {
          user: "XXXXX@gmail.com",
          pass: "YYYYY"
      }
  });
  var mailOptions = {
      from: "Team | <XXXXX@gmail.com>",
      to: user.email,
      subject: "Password Change",
      text: "Hello world",
      html: "Your password changed successfully."+ "Your new password is "+ "<style='color: red;'>"+ password +"</style>" // html body
  };   
  console.log(mailOptions);
  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
      if(error){
          console.log(error);
      }else{
          console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Looks like when run inside your app server, the outgoing SMTP connection to gmail's mail server doesn't work. Are you running this all locally or is the app server on a remote server? If so, perhaps the server has a firewall blocking outbound connections.

Comment: @PeterLyons I am using it on local server and as per the error message..I thought so about the firewall but it is sending mail when running it in a single file like - `node mail.js` and it is sending the mail successfully then. FYI - I am using frontend app which is hitting the api at another app and in that app I am using the code for sending an email

Comment: What do you get from `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465`, does it connect?

Comment: @MattHarrison `CONNECTED(00000003)` as I already mentioned that email is sending when running from a file.but in a request it fails.

Comment: I know, but just double checking as it sounds like a classic firewall issue

Comment: @MattHarrison Yeah my initial thought so..but make my head down when it runs successfully via a file

Comment: What happens if you remove the mongodb query and send the email in the express handler immediately?

Comment: @MattHarrison Yeah nice though let me chk this without in a query

Comment: @MattHarrison I removed the mongodb queries and still the same result though mail options are correctly formed http://pastebin.com/u5PyuV6x  Console.log result - http://pastebin.com/xNpiAZ3Z

Comment: Can you run `tcpdump -i eth0 -nnn port 25` on the server to and paste the output here?

Comment: @NitzanShaked Following is the result from current user/su(root) http://pastebin.com/C9hzXhjp

Comment: @Trialcoder: ok, then (as root) run `ifconfig`, find out what the interface name is used to send the mail, and run `tcpdump` again using that interface name instead of `eth0`.

Comment: @NitzanShaked this is the result http://pastebin.com/MKbZ42uK

Comment: Great. Then run (as root) `tcpdump -i eth1 -nnn port 25`, keep it running, and then trigger the mail-sending path ("forgot password") on the server.

Comment: @NitzanShaked ohh still the same error..though I started the server and as a suggestion i removed the query code this time ..but still the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57896/discussion-between-nitzan-shaked-and-trialcoder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a firewall issue. I am using `linemanjs` which is hitting the api via proxy and currently proxy is not supported in node mailer.

> Nodemailer does not support proxies and currently there is no plan to
>   add any support for these, sorry.

Reference - [Nodemailer Issue With Proxy](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/issues/125)

As a fix I installed nodemailer module on my clientapp(lineman app) and sending data to another app and receive token on the basis of which I am sending email via nodemailer.

Answer (score 0):

downgrade your node-mailer version 0.7.1

use this command in your terminal :- `npm install nodemailer@0.7.1 --save`

then check in your package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.8",
    "nodemailer": "^0.7.1"
}
```

It works for me.